# Blazor PWA hosted in kestrel - no automatic update?

Tags: caching, blazor, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am having a blazor PWA related problem, in an app that is hosted in kestrel webserver. For testing I have it installed on my android phone. Its working great, online and offline.
The "service-worker.published.js", I am using is exactly the same as in the default PWA template.

I can see that after publishing the app, the hashes of the included files change and also the final "service-worker.js" gets updated.

So everything looks good, but I cant get the app to update on my phone. To get an update I have to  uninstall it, then clear the browser cache and repeat the installation.

What am I missing here? Is it some setting in the webserver or is there anything missimg in the default "service-worker.published.js"? It looks like a very basic thing!

Greetings,
Frank

Comment: You need to restart the app at least twice to get the new one. This isn't a Blazor issue, this happens with all PWAs. The first time, the browser will detect there's a new service worker and download it but *not* install it. This will happen when the application restarts.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in my case its not updating at all, even if I restart it several times. I never get some alert in the app like "There is a new version, install?". Also I can see that its still the old version.

Comment: You never get any message, the browser retrieves the new version in the background. Have you tried this with a desktop browser? If you can't update on a desktop browser, you won't be able to do so in an occasionally connect phone. In the desktop browser's Developer Tools you can check the [registered Service Workers](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-debug-progressive-web-apps-using-browser-developer-tools-bad1cd3db784/) in the `Application` Tab. This will show if there's a newer version and even allow you to force the update, or unregister the service worker and start from scratch

Comment: That makes sense. I can see in the browsers devtools that a new version is available. But it doesnt get activated , I dont know why. I closed the browser several times and restarted , but no change. 
As soon as I click "Skip waiting" in the devtools, the new version gets activated and after the next start, the new version is in place. But this procedure should be automatic normally? The user normally has no chance to do it in the devtools.

Comment: Did you close *all* pages showing your site? The browser won't consider it closed until it's no longer shown by any page. This is done to ensure only one service worker is active at a time. Check the [Updates section](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#waiting) in Google's [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle). If the new worker is in the `Waitiing` state it means a tab is open

Comment: Finally its working, also on the phone! I am not totally sure what happend, because I didnt change anything in the configuartion. This is what I have done:
- I created a new version on the server
- Then I started chrome with the last version, there it showed: version #31. But no hint, that there is a new version.
- The I clicked "update" to force the update and then version #34 was found + activated. There is gap between #31 + #34, I dont no why.
- Then I repeated the whole process: created new version , started chome with #34.
- Now he showed in the devtools that #35 is waiting

Comment: Then I closed chrome, restarted and #35 was activated!
THX a lot for your helper Panagiotis!!

Comment: I encountered the same issues when I tried to deploy as a PWA - I keep forgetting to close *all* tabs.